# Can stunnel use the OS's certifificate store?

Tags: linux, stunnel, certificate-authority

I'm using stunnel in "client" mode to enable my non-SSL client to connect to an SSL server (it's using FIX protocol).

My set up works fine if I disable verification but then of course I'm lose MITM protection.

I can manually download the CA's pem and tell stunnel to use that, but is there a way to instead have it rely on linux's certificate store just like would happen if I were using a web browser, wget or openssl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux has no single "built-in" TLS library like SChannel on Windows, it has several, and as a result it has several "OS certificate stores" too – OpenSSL uses one format (well, two), NSS uses another, Java yet another.

As stunnel is based on OpenSSL, it can be configured to use either the CA file provided by the OS (which is literally just all CA .pem's concatenated):

```
CApath = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

or the "hashed" directory:

```
CAdir = /etc/ssl/certs
```

Paths may vary between distributions.